# How can I animate an overlayed div with :hover? Do I need JS or can it be done in CSS?

Tags: html, css, hover, overlay

**What I am trying to achieve:** As the mouse scrolls over a color section, that specific color section slides and overlays the other three, revealing more content.

**What I tried:**

Each time I add a div it affects the previous div because of its parent.

If a div gets added without a parent, the result was that each div animated solo.

Perhaps I am approaching this the wrong way. Do I need javascript to hide each individual div? Whats the best way to achieve this? Thank you

**Heres a code pen of what I have so far:**
https://codepen.io/habsqrd/pen/WNbrNLL

Here is the body:

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="one">
        <div class="two">
            <div class="three">
                <div class="four">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
  margin: auto;
}

.center {

}

.one {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  background-color:rgb(94, 226, 94);
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }

}

.one:hover {
    position: absolute;
    background-color:rgb(6, 179, 6);
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    z-index: 4;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  }

.two {
    position: absolute;
    background-color:rgb(247, 82, 82);
      width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;

  }

.three {
    position: absolute;
    background-color:rgb(86, 86, 255);
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
  } 


.four {
  position: absolute;
  background-color:rgb(240, 240, 96);
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: `that specific color section slides and overlays the other three, revealing more content.` what do you mean by that??

Comment: If the mouse hovers over a color, that color takes up the whole webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im hope i understand you correctly:

https://codepen.io/shahry4r/pen/yLyeyGV

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="center">
      <div class="one"></div>
      <div class="two"></div>
      <div class="three"></div> 
      <div class="four"></div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>

CSS

body
{
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
  margin: auto;
}

.center {

}

.one {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color:rgb(94, 226, 94);
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left:auto;  
  { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }

}

.one:hover {
    position: absolute;
    background-color:rgb(6, 179, 6);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 4;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  }

.two {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color:rgb(247, 82, 82);
      width: 25%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      left:25%;  
      z-index: 1;

  }

.two:hover {
    position: absolute;
    background-color:rgb(247, 82, 82);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 4;
    left:0%;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  }


.three {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color:rgb(86, 86, 255);
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
} 


.four {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color:rgb(240, 240, 96);
  width: 24%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 75%;  
  position: absolute;
}
```